# Dynamic population of ComboBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have few `ComboBox`es, and they are populated using an `ObservableList<String>` inside the `initialize()` method of my Controller class. When `initialize()` runs the `ObservableList<String>` is empty, therefore the `ComboBox`es are not populated. 
Anyway, through the GUI, the user can add items to the `ObservableList<String>,` but since the `initialize()` method was already executed the `ComboBox`es are not populated. How can i re-run the `initialize()` method?
Or is it better to add a `Listener`? I have tried this second option, but it seems that I cannot add a Listener to the `ObservableList<String>,` therefore I was thinking to re-run `initialize() somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are initializing the `ComboBox` to use the `ObservableList`, you do not need to reinitialize it.

To add items to the `ComboBox`, simply add them to the underlying `ObservableList`.

Quick example:

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

// Set the ComboBox to use the items list
comboBox.setItems(items);

// Allow the user to update the items in the list
items.add("A new String");
```

Since you are using an `ObservableList`, the `ComboBox` will **observe** the underlying list for changes and update its available items accordingly.

As such, it's usually not recommended to add/remove items to/from the `ComboBox` directly using `getItems.add()`, for example. Instead, modify just the `ObservableList`.

Comment: In your example there is no difference between `items` and `comboBox.getItems()` yield the same result. Of course you should modify the model directly if the `ObservableList` is part of the model, but you decide where this list is stored. If you choose to implement the logic in a way that makes sure it's the `ObservableList` from the model that is always assigned to the `ComboBox`'s `item` property there's absolutely nothing wrong with `comboBox.getItems().add(string)`

Comment: @fabian - hence the "usually" :) I find modifying the underlying list to be cleaner and a bit more obvious from a readability standpoint. Though, I know there are always exceptions.